# UK Direct Airside Transit Visa processing time

Tags: visas, uk, hong-kong, datv, sri-lankan-citizens

I am a Sri Lankan who lives in Hong Kong. I am travelling to France via UK. I have an airside transit. So DATV is required.

I am having a doubt in processing time of Direct Airside Transit Visa from the British Consulate for the following scenario:

The UKBA site says that [100% (!) of transit visa applications in Hong Kong are processed within 5 days.](http://www.ukba.homeoffice.gov.uk/countries/hong-kong/processing-times/?langname=UK%20English)

And also it says that [100% (!) of transit visa applications in Sri Lanka are processed within 40 days.](http://www.ukba.homeoffice.gov.uk/countries/sri-lanka/processing-times1/?langname=UK%20English)

Does anyone have an idea which time range is applicable for me (Sri Lankan who lives in Hong Kong) please?

Because for the moment I have only one month time period remaining.

Comment: The Hong Kong figure is probably the most relevant but I am not sure whether is matters all that much as you should probably apply as soon as possible in any case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank you for the all guidance.

I just want to share the real experience I had because I assume this will be helpful for others.

For the Direct Airside Transit Visa, it took around 8 working days for me.

Answer (score 3):

To me this information is pretty clear. It just depends on where you apply.

- Up to 5 days if you apply in Hong Kong.
- Up to 40 days if you apply in Sri Lanka.

Assuming that you are in Hong Kong now, you should obviously apply from there.

Comment: It would seem so but do you have any personal experience or other source of information to back that up?

Comment: No, I just clarified the information from the links posted in the question.